# Making inputs into a list isn't collecting the checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have a div on my website where there will be a varying amount of questions, each with two inputs. I have a button, which on being clicked, calls a JavaScript function, which puts it into a list. I want it in a list so that I can pass it to a django view and process the information in it.

The code for this is below:

```js
var button = $("#serialise");

$(button).click(function() {
  var vals = [];
  $("#questions :input").each(function(index) {
    vals.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(vals)


});
```

```html
<div id='questions'>
  <div id='q'>
    <label>Question: </label><input type="text" id="text" />
    <br>
    <label>Numeric: </label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  </div>

  <div id='q'>
    <label>Question: </label><input type="text" id="text" />
    <br>
    <label>Numeric: </label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>

<button id="serialise">Serialise</button>
```

The problem I am facing is that when I get all the values, regardless of wether the checkbox is checked or not, the value in the list I am getting is 'on'.

Here is an example:

[image: The inputs]

and this is what the function produces:

```
["Hey there", "on", "Stack Overflow", "on", "Please help <3", "on"]
```

Comment: ID should be unique in context use class instead

Comment: I have changed it and its still not working

Comment: What is your expected result? `["Hey there", "on", "Stack Overflow", "Please help <3", "on"]` or `["Hey there", "on", "Stack Overflow", "off", "Please help <3", "on"]`? If it is the first result, just change your select query to `#questions input[type=text], #questions input[type=checkbox]:checked`. For second result, add some simple if else statement in `each` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your javascript with this code, this should work

```
var button = $("#serialise");

$(button).click(function() {
    var vals = [];
    $("#questions :input").each(function(index) {

    if($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
        if($(this).prop("checked")) {
            vals.push('on');
        }
        else {
            vals.push('off');
        }
    }else {
        vals.push($(this).val());
    } 
  });
  console.log(vals)

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! It worked perfectly.

Comment: Always ready to help if i can

Answer (score 0):

`:checked` selector will help. Which is as follows:

```
$("#questions :input :checked").each(function(index){
  vals.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: The `:input` pseudo-selector is redundant

Comment: I am now getting a empty list, regardless of wether or not there is data entered